# Remove comma from list items using linq c#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list where I want to remove last comma from every list item, what is the best way to do it in c# linq

```
    var myList = new List<colors> {
      new Color {
        Id   = 1, 
        Name = "red,blue,green,orange," 
      },
      new Color {
        Id   = 2, 
        Name = "purple,sky blue, pink, red," 
      },
      new Color {
        Id   = 3, 
        Name = "green, yellow, black,"
      },
      new Color {
        Id   = 4, 
        Name = "white,black,red, blue,"
      }
   }
```

Is there any way to remove *last comma* from all items in a one go by using *Linq* c#?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; ++i) myList[i].Name = myList[i].Name.Trim(',');`

Comment: LINQ is generally not used to *modify* values. Please clarify how you expect LINQ to be used here. Also if you show what code you already have (I'm sure you simply forgot to add it to the question - please reconsider as lack of attempt may invite downvotes) it may help others to narrow down on approach.

Comment: In VS use replace  From : ,"  To : "

Answer (score 2):

Linq is excellent for *querying* data not for *modifying*; that's why I suggest a good old `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; ++i) 
  myList[i].Name = myList[i].Name.TrimEnd(',');
```

or if `Name` is init-only and we have to recreate `Color`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; ++i) 
  myList[i] = new Color() {
    Id   = myList[i].Id, 
    Name = myList[i].Name.TrimEnd(',')
  }
```

Technically, you can use *Linq*

```
myList = myList
  .Select(color => new Color() {
    Id   = color.Id,
    Name = color.Name.TrimEnd(',')
  })
  .ToList();
```

but it's *overshoot*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change your class `Color` definition as follows:

```
class Color
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    private string _name;
    public string Name{
        get{
            return _name;
        }
        set{
            _name = value.TrimEnd(',');
        }
    }
}
```

then when you create a list, the comma is auto removed, no need to do anything:

```
var mylist = new List<colors>{
  new Color{
    Id=1, 
    Name="red,blue,green,orange,"
  },
  new Color{
    Id=2, 
    Name="purple,sky blue, pink, red,"},
  new Color{
    Id=3, 
    Name="green, yellow, black,"
  },
  new Color{
    Id=4, 
    Name="white,black,red, blue,"
  }
}
```

[image]

**Approach 1:** add constructor to your class

```
public class Color
{
    public Color()
    {
    
    }
    
    public Color(Color source)
    {
        this.Id = source.Id;
        this.Name = source.Name.TrimEnd(',');
    }
    
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
void Main()
{
    var mylist = new List<Color>{
          new Color{
            Id=1, 
            Name="red,blue,green,orange,"
          },
          new Color{
            Id=2, 
            Name="purple,sky blue, pink, red,"},
          new Color{
            Id=3, 
            Name="green, yellow, black,"
          },
          new Color{
            Id=4, 
            Name="white,black,red, blue,"
          }
    };  

    var res = from c in mylist
              select new Color(c);
    Console.Write(res);
}
```

**Approach 2:** add a `RemoveComma()` method to your class

```
public class Color
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    
    public Color RemoveComma()
    {
        this.Name = this.Name.TrimEnd(',');
        return this;
    }
}
void Main()
{
    var mylist = new List<Color>{
          new Color{
            Id=1, 
            Name="red,blue,green,orange,"
          },
          new Color{
            Id=2, 
            Name="purple,sky blue, pink, red,"},
          new Color{
            Id=3, 
            Name="green, yellow, black,"
          },
          new Color{
            Id=4, 
            Name="white,black,red, blue,"
          }
    };  

    var res = from c in mylist
              select c.RemoveComma();
    Console.Write(res);
}
```

**Approach 3:** if you dont want to modify the `Color` class, define a extension method

```
public class Color
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

public static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static Color RemoveComma(this Color c)
    {
        c.Name = c.Name.TrimEnd(',');
        return c;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var mylist = new List<Color>{
          new Color{
            Id=1, 
            Name="red,blue,green,orange,"
          },
          new Color{
            Id=2, 
            Name="purple,sky blue, pink, red,"},
          new Color{
            Id=3, 
            Name="green, yellow, black,"
          },
          new Color{
            Id=4, 
            Name="white,black,red, blue,"
          }
    };  

    var res = from c in mylist
              select c.RemoveComma();
    Console.Write(res);
}
```